# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at "LPR_PROD.MPKG_LPKREPORT", line 21

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute the below query in oracle and i am getting the ORA-01422 error. Below is the query i am using to accomplish my results. This query is a part of Package.

```
Select DISTINCT TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy') "Disbursal Date",
RST.st_nam_s "State Name", MLO_COUNTY.loc_nam_s "County Name",RHR.d_pmtdu_s, 
MLO_CITY.loc_nam_s "City Name", RHR.recip_s "Original GeoCode", 
RHR.lse_s "Lease Number",RHR.unit_lse_s "Asset Number",
REQ.bk_acct_s "Contract Type", REQ.eqt_stat_s "Asset Status",
TO_CHAR(REQ.d_disp_s,'MM/dd/yyyy') "Asset Disposition Date",
RHR.p_st_rat_d "State Rate",(RHR.p_ct_rat_d-RHR.p_ct_trnst_rat_d) "County Rate",
RHR.p_ct_trnst_rat_d "County Transit Rate",
RHR.p_cy_rat_d -RHR.p_cy_trnst_rat_d) "City Rate", 
RHR.p_cy_trnst_rat_d "City Transit rate", 
RHR.p_st_rat_d +RHR.p_ct_rat_d+RHR.p_cy_rat_d) "Combined Rate", 
RHR.nontax_gross_d+RHR.gross_d) "Gross Invoice Billed",  
CASE WHEN trim(RHR.lse_s)='UPF STAX' THEN
mpkg_lpkreport.GROSSTAX(trim(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S),RHR.d_end_of_month_s,
trim(RHR.LSE_S),RHR.p_ct_rat_d) ELSE RHR.gross_d END "Taxable Invoice Billed",
mpkg_lpkreport.NCALACCUREDTAXVALUE(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S,0,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
RHR.LSE_S,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_pmtdu_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),RHR.p_ct_rat_d) "Accrued State Tax",
mpkg_lpkreport.NCALACCUREDTAXVALUE(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S,1,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
RHR.LSE_S,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_pmtdu_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),RHR.p_ct_rat_d ) "Accrued County Tax",
mpkg_lpkreport.NCALACCUREDTAXVALUE(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S,2,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
RHR.LSE_S,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_pmtdu_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),RHR.p_ct_rat_d) "Accrued City Tax",
mpkg_lpkreport.NCALACCUREDDISTRICTTAX(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S,1,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
RHR.LSE_S,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_pmtdu_s,'MM/dd/yyyy')) "Accrued County District Tax", 
mpkg_lpkreport.NCALACCUREDDISTRICTTAX(RHR.UNIT_LSE_S,2,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_end_of_month_s,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
RHR.LSE_S,TO_CHAR(RHR.d_pmtdu_s,'MM/dd/yyyy')) "Accrued City District Tax", 
TO_CHAR(RLS.d_com_s,'MM/dd/yyyy') "Lease commencement date",
REQ.txp_s "Tax payment code", 
replace((State_Geocodes.geo_st_l || substr(RHR.recip_s,3,length(recip_s))),'','')
"Translated GeoCode"   
from   RHR 
Inner join REQ on REQ.unit_s =RHR.unit_lse_s
and rhr.use_tax_c = case when REQ.txp_s in ('CNTY','CNCI' ) then '1'  when  REQ.txp_s = 'CITY' then 
'2' else '0' end 
Inner join RLS on RLS.lse_s = REQ.lse_s 
Inner join RST on REQ.st_s =RST.st_s 
Inner join MLO_COUNTY on MLO_COUNTY.ct_s =REQ.ct_s and MLO_COUNTY.st_s =REQ.st_s
Inner join MLO_CITY on MLO_CITY.cy_s =REQ.cy_s AND MLO_CITY.ct_s =REQ.ct_s
AND MLO_CITY.st_s =REQ.st_s 
Inner join State_Geocodes on State_Geocodes.ST_S=substr(RHR.recip_s,1,2) 
Where 1=1 and rhr.por_s =' 1' and rhr.d_end_of_month_s = '30-NOV-2017';
```

Is there anything i missed in the query?

Below is the function that has been used in the query mpkg_lpkreport.GROSSTAX. It is showing the error in this function and i am not sure what issue is in this.

```
FUNCTION GROSSTAX(sunit_lse_s varchar2,
sd_end_of_month_s date, slse_s varchar2, rat_d FLOAT) return FLOAT
AS
n_grossd FLOAT;
BEGIN
BEGIN
select nvl(gross_d,0) into n_grossd      from RHR
where trim(RHR.lse_s)=slse_s and trim(RHR.unit_lse_s)=sunit_lse_s
and RHR.use_tax_c IN ('0') and RHR.d_end_of_month_s=sd_end_of_month_s
and  RHR.P_CT_RAT_D=rat_d;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
n_grossd := 0;
END;
IF n_grossd = 0 THEN
BEGIN
select nvl(gross_d,0) into n_grossd      from RHR
where trim(RHR.lse_s)=slse_s and trim(RHR.unit_lse_s)=sunit_lse_s
and RHR.use_tax_c IN ('1') and RHR.d_end_of_month_s=sd_end_of_month_s
and  RHR.P_CT_RAT_D=rat_d;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
n_grossd := 0;
END;
END IF;
IF n_grossd = 0 THEN
BEGIN
select nvl(gross_d,0) into n_grossd      from RHR
where trim(RHR.lse_s)=slse_s and trim(RHR.unit_lse_s)=sunit_lse_s
and RHR.use_tax_c IN ('2') and RHR.d_end_of_month_s=sd_end_of_month_s
and  RHR.P_CT_RAT_D=rat_d ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
n_grossd := 0;
END;
END IF;
return n_grossd;
END GROSSTAX;
```

Comment: Do you really think someone can decipher this?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am getting this issue when the query is accessing the function. Is there any issue with the function? I have the updated the function that used in the package...

Comment: Very simple.  One of your "select ... into ..." is returning more than one value.  Run the selects directly and see which is the problem.

Comment: @OldProgrammer When i executing all the select statements they are returning no rows found.

Comment: Well, then either Oracle is lying to you, or you are not executing with the same data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one of the queries in your `GROSSTAX` function is returning more than one row, but because you're doing a `SELECT...INTO` these queries must return at most one row. One way to work around this is to rewrite `GROSSTAX`:

```
FUNCTION GROSSTAX(sunit_lse_s       IN varchar2,
                  sd_end_of_month_s IN date,
                  slse_s            IN varchar2,
                  rat_d             IN FLOAT)
  return FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (select GROSS_D
                 from RHR
                 where trim(RHR.lse_s) = slse_s and 
                       trim(RHR.unit_lse_s)=sunit_lse_s and
                       RHR.use_tax_c IN ('0', '1', '2') and 
                       RHR.d_end_of_month_s = sd_end_of_month_s and  
                       RHR.P_CT_RAT_D=rat_d
                 ORDER BY RHR.USE_TAX_C ASC)
  LOOP
    RETURN NVL(aRow.GROSS_D, 0);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN 0;
END GROSSTAX;
```

Here I've compressed the three queries into one, as it appeared that they only differed by the value of `RHR.USE_TAX_C` they were checking for. The results of the query are ordered in ascending order by RHR.USE_TAX_C so that it will give back the GROSS_D value associated with the minimum value of USE_TAX_C which exists, all other comparisons being the same. Only the first row returned by the query is used; once the first row is returned by the cursor the function returns.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug you query commenting line by line all calls of that functions.
For instance, this piece of code from your function can return >1 recs
 select nvl(gross_d, 0)
      into n_grossd
      from RHR
     where trim(RHR.lse_s) = slse_s
       and trim(RHR.unit_lse_s) = sunit_lse_s
       and RHR.use_tax_c IN ('0')
       and RHR.d_end_of_month_s = sd_end_of_month_s
       and RHR.P_CT_RAT_D = rat_d;